# Wrong behavior when try to insert and delete from details kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have master and details kendo grid, when I insert/delete the header everything is working fine, but When i try to insert more than one record in the details grid the create statement will loop for all inserted records (new and old ones) each time I try to add a new record, also when I try to delete a record from the details table, the view will call the create method instead of delete one.

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.ItemSuppliers)
    .Name("CreateItem_gridSuppliers")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.ItemCode).Title(MyResources.GridItemCode).Width(100);            
        columns.ForeignKey(p => p.SupplierID, Model.Suppliers, "SupplierID", "SupplierID").Title(MyResources.Supplier).Width(200).EditorTemplateName("SupplierForeignkeyEditor");        
        columns.Bound(p => p.SupplierNameE).Title(MyResources.SupplierNameE).Width(150);                      
        columns.Bound(p => p.CustomDutyPercentage).Title(MyResources.CustomDutyPercentage).Width(200);
        columns.Bound(p => p.CustomDutyRate).Title(MyResources.CustomDutyRate).Width(200);

        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit().Text(MyResources.EditText).UpdateText(MyResources.UpdateText).CancelText(MyResources.CancelText); command.Destroy().Text(MyResources.Delete); }).Width(170);
    })
    .ToolBar(toolBar =>
    {
        toolBar.Create().Text(MyResources.AddNewItem);
    })

                     .Events(e => e.Edit("gridEdit").Cancel("OnCancel").DataBound("CreateItem_gridSuppliers_GridDataBound").Change("ItemSupplierSaved"))
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
           .ClientDetailTemplateId("template")

    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(5)
        .ServerOperation(true)
                                        .Events(events => events.Error("gridErrorHandler"))
                                .Events(ev => ev.RequestEnd("ItemSupplierSaved"))
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(p => p.ItemSuppliersID);
            model.Field(p => p.ItemSuppliersID).Editable(false);
            model.Field(p => p.ItemCode).Editable(false);

        })
                                        .Read(read => read.Action("GetItemSuppliers", "Item", new { __cnv = Model.ConversationKey }))
                             .Update(update => update.Action("ItemSupplier_Update", "Item", new { __cnv = Model.ConversationKey }))
                             .Create(create => create.Action("ItemSupplier_Create", "Item", new { __cnv = Model.ConversationKey }))
                                             .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("ItemSupplier_Delete", "Item", new { __cnv = Model.ConversationKey }))
    ))
  <script id="template" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
      @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.ItemOrigins)
                        .Name("ItemOrigin_#=ItemSuppliersID#")
                        .Columns(columns =>
                        {
                            columns.Bound(p => p.ItemCode).Hidden();
                            columns.Bound(p => p.ItemSuppliersID).Title(MyResources.ItemSuppliersID).Width(120);
                            columns.Bound(p => p.ItemOriginID).Title(MyResources.ItemOriginID).Width(100);

                            columns.ForeignKey(p => p.OriginID, Model.Origins, "OriginID", "OriginNameE").Title(MyResources.OriginID).Width(100);

                            columns.Bound(p => p.ProductBarCode).Title(MyResources.ProductBarCode).Width(200); 
                            columns.Command(command => { command.Edit().Text(MyResources.EditText).UpdateText(MyResources.UpdateText).CancelText(MyResources.CancelText); command.Destroy().Text(MyResources.Delete); }).Width(190);
                        })
                        .ToolBar(toolBar =>
                        {
                            toolBar.Create().Text(MyResources.AddNewItem);
                        })
                        .Events(e => e.Edit("RemoveItemOriginFilter").Cancel("ReloadGrid"))
                        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine).DisplayDeleteConfirmation(true).DisplayDeleteConfirmation(MyResources.ItemOriginDeleteConfirm))

                        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                            .Ajax()
                            .PageSize(5)
                            .ServerOperation(true)

                                    .Events(events => events.Error("gridErrorHandler"))
                            .Model(model =>
                            {
                                model.Id(p => p.ItemOriginID);
                                model.Field(p => p.ItemOriginID).Editable(false);
                                model.Field(p => p.ItemSuppliersID).Editable(false);
                                model.Field(p => p.Origin);

                            })
                                                    .Read(read => read.Action("GetItemOrigin", "Item", new { itemSupplierID = "#=ItemSuppliersID#", __cnv = Model.ConversationKey }))
                                            .Update(update => update.Action("ItemOrigin_Update", "Item", new { itemSupplierID = "#=ItemSuppliersID#", __cnv = Model.ConversationKey }))
                                            .Create(create => create.Action("ItemOrigin_Create", "Item", new { itemSupplierID = "#=ItemSuppliersID#", __cnv = Model.ConversationKey }))
                                            .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("ItemOrigin_Delete", "Item", new { itemSupplierID = "#=ItemSuppliersID#", __cnv = Model.ConversationKey }))
                            )
                            .ToClientTemplate()
                        )
</script>
```

And here is my controller

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
 public ActionResult ItemOrigin_Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, ItemOriginViewModel item, int itemSupplierID, string __cnv)
{
     List<ItemOriginViewModel> itemOrigins = new List<ItemOriginViewModel>();
     if (Session["ItemOrigin_" + __cnv + itemSupplierID] != null)
        {
            itemOrigins = (List<ItemOriginViewModel>)Session["ItemOrigin_" + __cnv + itemSupplierID];

       if (item.UID == null)
        {
            item.UID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
             item.ItemSuppliersID = itemSupplierID;
             itemOrigins.Add(item);
         }
          else
         {
               int index = itemOrigins.FindIndex(x => x.UID == item.UID);
               itemOrigins[index] = item;
          }
     }
     else
     {
         item.UID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
         item.ItemSuppliersID = itemSupplierID;
         itemOrigins.Add(item);
     }
     Session["ItemOrigin_" + __cnv + itemSupplierID] = itemOrigins;     
      return Json(itemOrigins.ToDataSourceResult(request));            
  }



[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult ItemOrigin_Delete([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, ItemOriginViewModel item, string __cnv)
        {
            List<ItemOriginViewModel> itemOrigins = (List<ItemOriginViewModel>)Session["ItemOrigin_" + __cnv + item.ItemSuppliersID];
            int index = itemOrigins.FindIndex(x => x.ItemOriginID == item.ItemOriginID);
            itemOrigins.RemoveAt(index);
            Session["ItemOrigin_" + __cnv + item.ItemSuppliersID] = itemOrigins;
            var result = itemOrigins;
            return Json(result.ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }
```

Any suggestion please to solve this issue??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Kendo DataSource will attempt to send items that are marked as 'new' or 'dirty'. 'New' just means that the item ID (it looks like your ID column is `ItemSuppliersID`) is `undefined` or `0`. It will keep resending these items as long as that ID is not set.

Normally, your controller should return the item that was just inserted, but with the ID now set to the new value. Then Kendo will copy the ID from the response to the object on the client. Since the ID is then set, the item will no longer be marked 'new' and will stop being sent to the server.

In other words, if you POST:

```
{
    "ItemSuppliersID": 0,
    "ItemCode": "ABC"
}
```

then the controller should return:

```
{
    "ItemSuppliersID": 123, // <-- ID field is now set
    "ItemCode": "ABC"
}
```